# NODE [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module './config/app'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

**FIXED**, the names of the folders in my pc changed when uploaded to github

So, my app looks something like this

```
├── config
|    ├── app.js
|
└── index.js
```

**app.js**

Here i have all my env variables, so I have a central point from which to extract them

```
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
    appPort: process.env.PORT,
    appUrl: process.env.APP_URL,
    appKey: process.env.APP_KEY,
    frontendUrl: process.env.FRONTEND_URL
}
```

**index.js**

central file of the server

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

const { appPort, frontendUrl } = require('./config/app')

app.listen(appPort , () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${appPort}`);
})
```

The problem here is that when i deploy it and starts the server, it throws me error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
   throw err;
   ^
 
 Error: Cannot find module './config/app'
 Require stack:
 - /app/index.js
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:8:34)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
 }
```

and i really don't know why, because it works perfectly fine in my pc

the code for the whole project is actually much bigger, but only this files are the ones throwing me errors

Hope someone can help see what is happening that throws that error

Comment: If the problem only occurs when you deploy it, then the problem must be with your deployment process (which we can't see) and you need to debug it (e.g. by examining the file paths and permissions on the server).

Comment: i'm using heroku to delpoy it, i just connected it with my github and the repo of the project and it just deploy it automatically